# Could this be done more efficiently

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns (p_id, id_type) where the p_id can have multiple types.  I need to find the p_ids that do not have a specific type.

```
P_ID                    ID_TYPE
-----------          -------------
12456                      6
12456                      7 
56897                      10
25686                      9
25686                      22
25686                      7
56897                      22
```

This is the query I used but wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
select p_id 
into #temp1
from table2
where id_type = 6

SELECT  
distinct table2.p_id 
,table1.NAME
,table1.TYPE

FROM 
table2 left join table1
on table2.p_id = table1.p_id
where 
table2.p_id not in
  (select p_id from #temp1)
and type = 'XYZ'
```

Expected outcome should be those P_IDs that DO NOT have an ID_TYPE = 6.

```
P_ID         Name          Type
56897        Smith         Physician
25686        Jones         Physician
```

Comment: Can you add the expected result please?

Comment: Your code was fine. You could just do away with the creation of the temp table and handle getting the p_ids with an id_type = 6 in your inner select which you are already doing but in a longer way.

Comment: what do you mean by `I need to find the p_ids that do not have a specific type.` ?

Comment: Expected outcome should be those P_IDs that DO NOT have an ID_TYPE = 6. 

    P_ID         Name          Type
    56897        Smith         Physician
    25686        Jones         Physician

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to select all the p_id rows that don't have any corresponding p_id rows with a specific type.

If so, there are a couple of ways to do this.  One is to use `NOT IN`:

```
select *
from yourtable
where p_id not in (
  select p_id
  from yourtable
  where id_type = 6)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1df6b/2)

---

Using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from yourtable t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable t2
  where t.p_id = t2.p_id and 
        t2.id_type = 6)
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1df6b/5)

---

You could also use an `OUTER JOIN` to achieve the same result.

If you want just specific p_id's, then you need to add `DISTINCT`.  It's not clear what you're expected output should be.

Comment: +1 for excluding a single id_type this is better than having count case

Answer (score 0):

A more SQLy way to do this is to use a single left join to find something called a [Relative Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)). Essentially what we want to say is "Take all of the `p_id`, then take away all the ones that have an `id_type` of 6".

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.p_id
FROM table2 AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t.p_id = t2.p_id
  AND t2.id_type = 6
WHERE t2.p_id IS NULL
```